# Saving the output of the function

Tags: r

I have a very complex function. It takes 5 days to give me
 me the output. Sometime, after I get the result, I need to shut down my computer. Then, when I would like to extract some values (output) of my function, I need to rerun the function again and wait for 5 days again.

Is there a way that I can comeback to the result of my function at any time even when I quit R? How can I come back to the result of my function without re-running it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options. First, assuming that you set a variable equal to the function output you could use `save.image()` with a `.RData` ending and this could save global environment variables. You could then load this `.RData` file the the next time and you want to see the output. Another possibility is to use `write.table()` or a similar function to save a `.txt` or `.csv` file if your output is a matrix or vector. You could then load this output in another session.

Answer (score 0):

You can **store your output to a file** by using **sink function** in R studio
The **sink** function can force all output to a file

Redirecting output to a file include 3 steps:

1. Redirect output to a file name output.file

   > sink("output.txt")
2. Run the script to capture its output, where script.R is the name of the script file containing the program

   > source("script.R")
3. Resume writing output to console

   > sink()

That's it now your program's output has been saved in a file